# Are there Latin verbs with Greek cognates in all four conjugations?

Tags: greek, verbs, conjugation

Off the top of my head, I can think of a few Latin verbs with obvious Greek cognates: *pherō~ferō* "to bear", *pheugō~fugiō* "to flee".

But all the words I can think of are in the third conjugation. Are there any first-, second-, and fourth-conjugation verbs with straightforward Greek relatives?

Comment: Detail: do the Greek cognates have to be verbs at all? Do they need to have vowels corresponding to the Latin vowels?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, lots, though some are less obvious because of sound changes etc. Examples:

1st conjugation: *dō* : δίδωμι, *stō* : ἵστημι, *vocō* : εἶπον

2nd conjugation: *videō* : εἶδον, οἶδα, *moneō* : μιμνήσκω, *maneō* : μένω, *pleō* : πίμπλημι

4th conjugation: *veniō* : βαίνω, *saliō* : ἅλλομαι, *potior* : δεσ-πότης